# nginx container uses only one out of 4 cores

Tags: nginx, docker, cpu-usage, high-load, cgroup

created an Nginx container with 4 static CPUs

```
docker run -tid --cpus 4 --cpuset-cpus 6,7,8,9 --net=host --name mynginx nginx

docker exec -ti mynginx cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf|grep worker_processes

worker_processes  auto;
```

**Assigned CPUs**

```
taskset -acp 1426038
pid 1426038's current affinity list: 6-9
```

**Sending Traffic:**

```
ab -n 10000000 -c 1000 http://172.16.91.5:80/
```

On top i can see that core 6 is used where as all the remaining cores are idle.

**from top-Nginx Cores**

```
 %Cpu6  : 14.6 us, 57.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 28.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
 %Cpu7  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
 %Cpu8  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
 %Cpu9  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

**OS Cores**

```
 %Cpu0  :  0.0 us,  2.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 32.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi, 65.1 si,  0.0 st
 %Cpu1  :  0.0 us,  5.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 40.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi, 53.7 si,  0.0 st
 %Cpu2  :  0.0 us,  0.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 29.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi, 69.2 si,  0.0 st
```

**load average:**

```
    34.84, 19.62, 8.36
```

Any explanation to this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that nginx uses a hash of the client IP to select a worker from the pool. Since with `ab` all connections come from the same IP address, they all end up processed by single worker, therefore loading only one CPU core.

Comment: That's a great suggestion - @ananthan could try this by sending traffic from more client machines

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have added one more client and repeated the test..but still all the remaining CPUs are idle.While load average shot up further.